# Remove double curly braces while creating JObject C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am trying to create JsonObject with the below-mentioned structure.

```
{
      "id": "1",
      "name": "XXX",
      "age": "30"
    }
```

Using the code,

```
dynamic sampleJson = new JObject();
                sampleJson.Add("id", "1");
                sampleJson.Add("name", "XXX");
                sampleJson.Add("age", "30");
```

But the problem is that extra curly braces is appearing at the begining and end of the json structure, as shown below.

```
{{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "XXX",
  "age": "30"
}}
```

I use the required JSON structure as the post body of an API and it should be in the JSON format(So cant use JSON string structure using ToString() method).How can I remove the extra braces and achieve my requirement ???

Comment: How are you generating the JSON? This should work fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove double curly brackets from JObject that have been added during deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41266503/remove-double-curly-brackets-from-jobject-that-have-been-added-during-deserializ)

Comment: If your API accepts a raw JSON then your current JSON with double curly bracket should do fine. How are you sure it is the problem?

Answer (score 6):

ToString() didn't work for me. The following did:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSONStringHere, typeof(ExpandoObject));
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using a `JObject`, you can simply call the [`ToString()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToString.htm) override to create your JSON. For example:

```
JObject sampleJson = new JObject();
sampleJson.Add("id", "1");
sampleJson.Add("name", "XXX");
sampleJson.Add("age", "30");

var json = sampleJson.ToString();
```

Now your `json` variable will contain:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "XXX",
  "age": "30"
}
```

Comment: calling the ToString() method, I am getting the post body as(using charles)"{\r\n  \"id\": \"1\",\r\n  \"name\": \"XXX\",\r\n  \"age\": \"30\"\r\n}" , which is not in the expected format

Comment: First what is charles? Second, I don't know how you are displaying that JSON, but I guarantee it gives you the detail in the right format.