# Remove double curly brackets from JObject

Tags: c#, json

I have a XYZ.Json file with following content.

```
{
  "ABC": "Account",
  "CDE": "Balance",
  "EFG": "Enquiry"
}
```

Using the following code I'm trying to read and return JObject from this Json, but extra curly braces is added at the beginning and end of the json structure.

```
JObject obj1 = JObject.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@".\XYZ\install\XYZ.json));
```

obj1:

```
{{
  "ABC": "Account",
  "CDE": "Balance",
  "EFG": "Enquiry"
}}
```

I have tried this [option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41266503/remove-double-curly-brackets-from-jobject-that-have-been-added-during-deserializ), converting `Jobject.Tostring()` but it didn't work.

Also tried this code, but still I see the same issue.

```
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    JObject obj = JObject.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@".\XYZ\install\XYZ.json));

    foreach (JProperty prop in obj.Properties())
    {
        dict.Add(prop.Name, obj.GetValue(prop.Name).ToObject<string>());
    };


    JObject obj3 = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict));
```

obj3:

```
{{
  "ABC": "Account",
  "CDE": "Balance",
  "EFG": "Enquiry"
}}
```

Please suggest if there are any other solutions.

Comment: Clarify how exactly you print this information and where, seems like that's your issue - in printing information, because according to https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDictionary.htm everything should work fine. And please, make sure to put a second " :) because you use @" and forgot to put a second, closing "

Comment: Have an explanation at this GitHub [thread](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2154) Calling `ToString` removes an extra braces

Comment: Agree with PavelAnikhouski above.  I believe this is just a debugger visualization "feature" which is confusing you.  To determine the literal JSON for `obj1` without any Visual Studio mangling you can print it to the console window by typing `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(obj1)` in the [immediate window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/immediate-window?view=vs-2019).  The output shown will be the JSON output for `obj1` without any VS prettification.

Comment: Thank you @PavelAnikhouski. As you said, it is just a debugger visualization in VS2017 but didn't create any problem in run-time, everything works normally.

Answer (score 2):

,You have to convert dictionary to json format first

```
    JObject obj = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\test.txt"));
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (JProperty prop in obj.Properties())
    {
        dict.Add(prop.Name, obj.GetValue(prop.Name).ToObject<string>());
    };

    var entries = dict.Select(d => string.Format($@"""{d.Key}"": ""{d.Value}"""));
    string convertedString = "{" + string.Join(",", entries) + "}";
    JObject obj3 = JObject.Parse(convertedString);
```

obj3 will give you same object as the obj.

**Double Curly braces are internal represenation** of a Json object. You cant remove the doubly braces as thats how json is represented in a JObject. Conversion from Json to Dictionary and then back to Json works correctly in the code above.

Both obj and obj3 variables look like following.

[image]

**NOTE**: Your example only works with string: string json .. if you have strin:object, this wont work.

Comment: Thanks @Jawad. As PavelAnikhouski mentioned in the link, it is just a debugger visualization in VS2017, no issues now.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing json with JObject.Parse is adding extra curly brackets to the json data. You can remove it by adding (string) conversion keyword.

Example

```
JObject jsonData= JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var specificData = (string)jsonData[myJsonName1][myJsonName2]
```

Converting string is the key part here. That solved my problem.