# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject throws exception when deserializing CouchBase response

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, json.net, couchbase

I'm trying to deserialize JSON response from CouchBase. However, deserialization throws an exception.

```
            IQueryRequest queryRequest = QueryRequest.Create(queryString);
            queryRequest.ScanConsistency(ScanConsistency.RequestPlus);
            var queryResult = await bucket.QueryAsync<dynamic>(queryRequest);

            if (!queryResult.Success)
            {
            }

            foreach (var row in queryResult.Rows)
            {
                try
                {
                    var registrationDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<RegistrationModel>>(row);
                    //var registrationDetail1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RegistrationModel>(row);
                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                { }

            }
```

Exception I'm getting:

```
{Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MC4B_CommonInterface.RegistrationModel>>(string)' has some invalid arguments
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at DataAccess.Services.RegistrationDataServices.ActivateSimpleRegistrations(ActivateRequest request) ...}
```

Response from Couchbase is straightforward. `RegistrationModel` has all the `JsonProperty` attributes.

```
[
  {
    "acsPntDocId": "",
    "adLis": "[]",
    "adP2DNa": "CA",
     .....
    }
]
```

One thing I've noticed, is the `foreach (var row in queryResult.Rows)`, `row` contains `{{"acsPntDocId":"","adLis": "[]", ...}}`

Comment: You can't deserialize into an interface.  You have to specifiy a concrete implementation, like `List<T>`.

Comment: Is adLis supposed to be a collection? If so the JSON/ your model is wrong. Post your model.

Comment: @newprint just to confirm, you're saying that the `row` value appears to have oddly formed JSON? I'm not a JSON guru, but that doesn't look right to me. Having the double curly braces and the empty array is quoted.

Comment: Check out the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41266503/remove-double-curly-brackets-from-jobject-that-have-been-added-during-deserializ  That row object may already be a JObject.

Comment: @newprint are you sure that the variable row is a string ? If it isn't you will get errors from newtonsoft json. Please verify that row is actually a string

Comment: @newprint you are calling JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T> on a dynamic. This does not fail at compile time, but at runtime it throws because the dynamic binding for the method fails (the method expects a string, but the object you passed is not a string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the string result you posted at the end of the question, it could be that `row` is already be a JObject. Based on this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/44308752/579148 it seems that adding `.ToString()` to the jobject before deserializing it may do the trick for you.

For example:

```
string rowString = row.ToString();
var registrationDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<RegistrationModel>>(rowString);
```